# NTFS Drive write access denied

Tags: permissions, ntfs

In Ubuntu I tried to play with the permission of NTFS drive. I installed an app from the Ubuntu Software Center named NTFS Configuration Tool. After using it a few times, the app started to close and wasn't responding. So I removed the app.

The next day I opened my PC, started the torrent client Transmission. That was a huge file so I downloaded that to my NTFS drive. So I resumed the torrent, but it said Permission denied to write. :( It seems like all of my NTFS drives have become read-only. I can't write anything.

How can I fix this permanently?

(I've run Transmission using sudo command. It's working, but using sudo command everywhere isn't the solution, I need it back like it was before. Please help.)

Here are my fstab contents:

[image]

Comment: I can't figure it out. :( 
http://screencloud.net/v/mKuP Its my fstab, what to change?

Comment: Try adding this to the bottom of the file:`/dev/sdax       /media/xxxx ntfs-3g  defaults  0   0`  make sure you replace x with you drive's ID, and xxxx with the name.

Comment: This is for one drive right? But I've problem in all the drives.

Comment: Got it. Everythings alright now.
fstab looks like this: http://screencloud.net/v/ixhT